# What is the meaning of "Colin made him mine"?

Tags: meaning

Cora changed the tune made by Sophie and Alex,
so Sophie didn't like it and Alex convincing Sophie
for not to interrupt Cora's decision. Colin is Cora's
friend.

> Because behind all her Buddhism-in-a-thong philosophy  what she cares
>   about is seats filled and units sold.  Nothing's gonna make her your
>   pal any more than years with **Colin made him mine**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to understand this is understanding what **mine** means. The sentence is made up of two clauses. The first clause is

> Nothing's gonna **make her your pal**

The second clause is

> any more than years with Colin **made him mine.**

You can now see that **mine** in the second clause corresponds to **your pal** in the first, so **mine** is possessive pronoun which stands in for **my pal**.

So the second clause really means

> any more than years with Colin **made him my pal.**

Answer (score 1):

> Nothing's gonna make her your pal any more than years with Colin made
>   him mine.

means

> Nothing's gonna make her your pal any more than years with Colin made
>   him ***my pal***.

The use of "mine" repeats the previous idea, but applied to "me".